# Mod_Rewrite Folder Directory to PHP File

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, redirect, directory

I have been resarching but haven't found anything exactly like what I am trying to do. Most are more advanced than what I want to accomplish. So basically I want to redirect a folder to an actual .php file.

For example: () = folder

```
(site)
  events.php
  (events)
    category.php
    (category)
```

I don't want users to be able to go to the folder level and redirect to the acutal php file. When they type www.site.com/events it redirects to www.site.com/events.php

Any input?

Comment: Well, you could put `DirectoryIndex foldername.php` in a `.htaccess` for each folder. =]  Or, you can do what most people do and create an `index.php` in each folder that acts as the entrance and prevents directory listing. (ie, change `events.php` to `index.php`)

Comment: I already have an index.php, and the events.php stands at the same level as index.php. As well as the folder (events)

Comment: Figured out what you meant and put the index.php inside the folder. Easy.lol

Comment: I figured you'd get it =]